# UI Router $state.go with params animating a parent state twice (Only in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, routes, angular-ui-router

I am having an issue with ui-router and the $state.go method with params.

When clicking on a building unit while the building overview state is expanded. The buildingOverview controller is run again which then animates the overview panel again.

The weird part about this is I only have this issue while in chrome.

The panels work as intended in all other browsers.

If I adjust the url to /?buildingID or /?id the panel works as intended however, I don't get the HTML5/SEO friendly URLS.

Please see attached video and code.

https://vimeo.com/173318836

**My index.route.js**

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mrkb')
        .config(routerConfig);

    /** @ngInject */
    function routerConfig($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider
            .state('building', {
                abstract: true,
                'url': '/bldg',
                views: {
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/building/index.html',
                        controller: 'BuildingController as building'
                    },
                    'building-overview@building': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/building/overview/overview.html',
                        controller: 'BuildingOverviewController as buildingOverview'
                    },
                    'building-map@building': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/building/map/map.html',
                        controller: 'BuildingMapController as buildingMap'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('building.landing', {
                'url': '/landing',
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/building/index.html',
                    controller: 'BuildingController as building'
                }
            })

            .state('building.overview', {
                'url': '/:buildingID',
                views: {
                    'building-overview@building': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/building/overview/overview.html',
                        controller: 'BuildingOverviewController as buildingOverview',
                        resolve: {
                            init: ['BuildingResultModel', '$timeout', function(BuildingResultModel, $timeout){
                                if(!BuildingResultModel.expanded){
                                    $timeout(function(){
                                        BuildingResultModel.expanded = true;
                                    },50);
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('building.detail', {
                'url': '/:buildingID/:id',
                views: {
                    'building-detail@building': {
                        'templateUrl': 'app/building/detail/detail.html',
                        'controller': 'BuildingDetailController as buildingDetail',
                        resolve: {
                            init: ['BuildingResultModel', '$timeout', function(BuildingResultModel, $timeout){
                                if(!BuildingResultModel.expanded && !BuildingResultModel.detailExpanded){
                                    $timeout(function(){
                                        BuildingResultModel.expanded = true;
                                        BuildingResultModel.detailExpanded = true;
                                    },50);

                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/bldg/landing');
    }

})();
```

**The Detail Controller**

```
    (function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mrkb')
        .controller('BuildingMapController', BuildingMapController);

    function BuildingMapController ($log, $state, BuildingResultModel, $timeout){
        var vm = this;

        vm.mapModel = BuildingResultModel;
        vm.mapModel.currentBldgID = $state.params.buildingID;

        vm.navigateToBuildingState = function(bldgNum){
            if(!BuildingResultModel.expanded){
                $timeout(function(){
                    BuildingResultModel.expanded = true;
                    BuildingResultModel.shiftMap = true;
                }, 50);
            }

            BuildingResultModel.detailExpanded = false;

            // reset filter by building names and plan types array
            BuildingResultModel.currentBldgNames = [''];
            BuildingResultModel.FloorPlanTypeAvailability = [''];

            $state.go('building.overview', { buildingID:bldgNum });
        };

        // Navigate to landing
        vm.navigateToLanding = function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            BuildingResultModel.detailExpanded  = false;

            $timeout(function(){
                BuildingResultModel.expanded = false;
                BuildingResultModel.shiftMap = false;
            },50);

            $state.go('building.landing');
        }
    }

})();
```

**Overview Controller (First Panel)**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('mrkb')
        .controller('BuildingOverviewController', BuildingOverviewController);

    function BuildingOverviewController($log, $state, BuildingResultModel, $timeout){
        var vm = this;
        vm.overviewModel = BuildingResultModel;

        // set BuildingResultModel for current building number to building ID passed in from state params
        BuildingResultModel.currentBldgID = $state.params.buildingID;

        // detail panel with building ID as param
        vm.viewDetail = function(id){
            $timeout(function(){
                BuildingResultModel.detailExpanded = true;
            },50);

            $state.go('building.detail', { buildingID:BuildingResultModel.currentBldgID, id:id });
        };

        // Static floor plan items
        vm.floorPlanItems = [
            {
                icon: 'icon-makoa-coaster',
                name: 'Makoa',
                bedroom: '3 Bedroom'
            },
            {
                icon: 'icon-leilani-coaster',
                name: 'Leilani',
                bedroom: '3 Bedroom + Den'
            },
            {
                icon: 'icon-kahua-coaster',
                name: 'Kahua',
                bedroom: '4 Bedroom'
            }
        ];

        // Set Active Floor Plan Filter
        vm.floorPlanItemsActive = vm.floorPlanItems;

        vm.setActive = function(filterItem) {
            vm.floorPlanItemsActive = filterItem;
        };

        vm.residenceItemsActive = BuildingResultModel.allBuildings;

        // Set Active Residence Unit
        vm.setActiveResidence = function(id) {
           vm.residenceItemsActive = id;
        }

        vm.AvailabiltyOptions = [
            {
                availability: 'available'
            },
            {
                availability: 'sold'
            },
            {
                availability: 'pending'
            }
        ];

        vm.filterByFloorPlan = function(name){
            // Remove default class from the three floorplan filters
            vm.overviewModel.filterFloorplanItemDefault = false;

            BuildingResultModel.currentBldgNames = [];
            BuildingResultModel.FloorPlanTypeAvailability = [''];
            BuildingResultModel.currentBldgNames.push(name.toLowerCase());
        };

        vm.filterByAvailability = function(availability){
            BuildingResultModel.FloorPlanTypeAvailability = [];
            BuildingResultModel.FloorPlanTypeAvailability.push(availability);
        }

        vm.resetFilters = function () {
            BuildingResultModel.FloorPlanTypeAvailability = [''];
        }
    }
})();
```

**Map Template**

```
<div class="mapped-item-1"
     ng-class="{'active': buildingMap.mapModel.currentBldgID == 1}"
     ng-click="buildingMap.navigateToBuildingState(1)">
    <span class="building-text">Building</span><br />
    <span class="building-number">1</span>
    <div class="map-arrow"></div>
</div>

<div class="mapped-item-5"
     ng-class="{'active': buildingMap.mapModel.currentBldgID == 5}"
     ng-click="buildingMap.navigateToBuildingState(5)">
    <span class="building-text">Building</span><br />
    <span class="building-number">5</span>
    <div class="map-arrow"></div>
</div>

<div class="mapped-item-2"
     ng-class="{'active': buildingMap.mapModel.currentBldgID == 2}"
     ng-click="buildingMap.navigateToBuildingState(2)">
    <span class="building-text">Building</span><br />
    <span class="building-number">2</span>
    <div class="map-arrow"></div>
</div>

<div class="overlay">

</div>

<div class="map-hit-area" ng-click="buildingMap.navigateToLanding($event)"></div>
```

**First Panel Template (Overview Panel)**

```
<header class="building-panel-header">
    <h4>Select Floorplan</h4>
</header>

<!-- Floor Plan Options Filter-->
<ul class="building-panel-floorplans">
    <li ng-repeat="floorPlan in buildingOverview.floorPlanItems">
        <a ng-href="#"
           ng-click="buildingOverview.filterByFloorPlan(floorPlan.name); buildingOverview.setActive(floorPlan)"
           ng-class="{ 'active' : buildingOverview.floorPlanItemsActive === floorPlan, default: buildingOverview.overviewModel.filterFloorplanItemDefault == true }">
            <i class="icon {{floorPlan.icon}}"></i>
            <span>{{floorPlan.name}}</span>
            <p>{{floorPlan.bedroom}}</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>


<!-- Units -->
<h4>Select Residences</h4>
<ul class="building-panel-units">
    <li ng-repeat="building in building.buildingModel.allBuildings | filterMultipleKeyValues: {buildingID: building.buildingModel.currentBldgID, name:building.buildingModel.currentBldgNames, availability:building.buildingModel.FloorPlanTypeAvailability}">
        <a href="#"
           class="{{building.availability}} "
           ng-class="{'active': buildingOverview.residenceItemsActive === building.id }"
           ng-click="buildingOverview.viewDetail(building.id, building.name); buildingOverview.setActiveResidence(building.id);">
            <i class="icon icon-{{building.name}}-coaster"></i>
            <span class="building-panel-unit-number">{{building.id}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>


<!-- Unit Availability Filter-->
<div class="building-panel-options">
    <button ng-repeat="availabiltyOption in buildingOverview.AvailabiltyOptions"
            ng-click="buildingOverview.filterByAvailability(availabiltyOption.availability)"
            ng-dblclick="buildingOverview.resetFilters()"
            class="btn {{availabiltyOption.availability}}">{{availabiltyOption.availability}}
    </button>
</div>
```